# How to fill input elements by their class name

Tags: javascript, input, getelementsbyclassname

I met some trouble while trying to fill some input elements.

I use javascript for that.

I use the method `getElementsByClassName('name_of_class')` to collect the nodes of elements.

Then I try to run through this node using a loop, but I do not succeed when I try to fill all elements input with the same value which is asked with the prompt.

In fact I assume that I'm wrong when I try to use `document.getElementByClassName('name_class').value`, because it is not a unique element, but I really have no Idea, when I do my loop in how to fill this inputs, because they are created dynamicly and they have no Id.

Here is my code

```
function saisie_titre(){
    choix = prompt("Veuillez saisir le titre :", '');
    var i;
    var checkboxList = document.getElementsByClassName( 'titre' );
    for ( i = 0; i < checkboxList.length; i++ ) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('titre').value = choix;
        //Here is the wrong part of my code

        console.log(choix);
    }
 }
```

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the index to the array. You already have the array stored in a variable so no need to get the elements again.

```
for ( i = 0; i < checkboxList.length; i++ ) {
    checkboxList[i].value = choix;
    console.log(choix);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the reference to the checkboxList, just access it as an array.

```
var checkboxList = document.getElementsByClassName( 'titre' );
for ( i = 0; i < checkboxList.length; i++ ) {
    checkboxList[i].value = choix;
```

Answer (score 1):

Working example at JsFiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/2UZXm/1/**

**-- Sample HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="titre"></input>
<input type="text" class="titre"></input>
<input type="text" class="titre"></input>
<input type="text" class="titre"></input>
<input type="button" id="terror" value="Click" />
```

**-- Sample JavaScript**

```
function saisie_titre() {
    choix = prompt("Veuillez saisir le titre :", '');
    var i;
    var checkboxList = document.getElementsByClassName('titre');
    for (i = 0; i < checkboxList.length; i++) {
        checkboxList[i].value = choix;
        console.log(choix);
    }
}
document.getElementById('terror').onclick = function () {
    saisie_titre();
}
```